# Вернуть статус ответа на GraphQL

Tags: java, graphql

Пишу `API` на GraphQL, с которым работает фронтэнд-приложение. Нужно возвращать фронтэндеру что-то вроде `status OK` и `error 404`. Как это сделать на джаве? GraphQL работает по многим протоколам и не специализирован именно для `HTTP`.

Comment: ну а фронт-энд по какому протоколу работает, известно?

Comment: Фронт работает по http